# Ansible error when using copy module for copying files

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

i keep getting this when trying out Ansible 2.1.0.0

```
- name: Copy Middleware Installer
   copy: src={{ mw_installer }}
        dest={{ installables_home }}
        owner={{ oracle_user }}
        group={{ oracle_group }}
```

I am trying to copy the mw installer that is 1 GB. the target system has 16 GB memory and has lot of space left..the master from where i run ansible has 1 GB of RAM.

```
An exception occurred during task execution. The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py",line 124, in run
res = self._execute()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 446, in _execute
result = self._handler.run(task_vars=variables)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/action/copy.py", line 156, in run source_full = self._loader.get_real_file(source_full)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/parsing/dataloader.py", line 334, in get_real_file
data = f.read()
MemoryError

fatal: [10.135.239.23]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}
```

If i use synchronize module

```
- name: Copy Middleware Installer
  synchronize: src={{ mw_installer }}
    dest={{ installables_home }}
    set_remote_user=no
```

it is asking for password

Answer (score 0):

`data = f.read()` suggests that ansible reads a file (to check wether it  is encrypted or not).
You should consider using `synchronize` module instead.

Comment: it is asking for password if i use synchronize

Comment: @chandra run playbook with `-vvvv` and check that user is correct, you may want to use different `become_user` for this task.

Comment: i am passing the password when i execute the playbook by using -k, but when the playbook comes to this task it stops and asks for password. i dont know why it is happening.